# Breeze Predicate in sub query

Tags: breeze, predicate

I have two entities, let's call them Alpha and Beta.

There is a one to many relationship between them, such that Beta has a foreign key to Alpha, `MyAlphaId`, and thus a reference property `MyAlpha`.

I have a predicate being built for Alphas.

e.g.

```
var predicateAlpha = new Predicate('name', 'contains', 'somevalue');
```

I want to then "transpose" this onto a query for Beta's where its `myAlpha` property matches that predicate.

e.g.

```
var predicateBeta = new Predicate('myAlpha', 'in', predicateAlpha);
```

I am aware of the ability for me to construct the predicate in the following manner:

```
var predicateBeta = new Predicate('myAlpha.name', 'contains', 'somevalue');
```

My issue is that I don't know what that predicate may be. I can't just pre-pend `'myAlpha.'` as it may include an OData function such as `'concat('somefield', 'someotherfield')'`.

Any other thoughts or suggestions on how I can achieve this?

For me, it would make sense for IN to accept a predicate that allows this to happen... I can't see the source code accepting a predicate so I can't think how else to make this happen...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Alpha` has a property `betas`, you could query for Alphas using the predicate, and `expand` the Betas so that they are brought in too.  Then collect the Betas if you need them in a single list:

```
var query = em.createQuery(predicateAlpha).expand('betas');
var betas = [];
em.executeQuery(query).then(queryResult => {
    queryResult.results.forEach(alpha => {
        betas = betas.concat(alpha.betas);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, that did cross my mind and in fact is the work around that I used, it just brings its own limitations within my architecture framework.